# How can I label connected components in APL?

Tags: connected-components, apl, dyalog

I'm trying to do leet puzzle https://leetcode.com/problems/max-area-of-island/, requiring labelling connected (by sides, not corners) components.

How can I transform something like

```
0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 1 1 0 1
0 1 0 0 1
0 1 0 0 1
```

into

```
0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 2 2 0 3
0 2 0 0 3
0 2 0 0 3
```

I've played with the stencil `⌺` operator and also tried using scan operators but still not quite there. Can somebody help?

Comment: Hi, I did something similar for advent of code https://github.com/rak1507/Advent-Of-Code-APL/blob/main/2021/Day09.dyalog, maybe that can help? {(×⍵)×⍵⌈⊃⌈/0 shifts ⍵}⍣≡{(1+⍳+/,⍵)@⊢⍵}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can start off by enumerating the ones. We do the by applying the function `⍸` (where, but since all are 1s, it is equivalent to 1,2,3,…) `@` **at** the subset masked by `⊢` the bits themselves, i.e. `⍸@⊢`:

```
      ⍸@⊢m
0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 2 3 0 4
0 5 0 0 6
0 7 0 0 8
```

Now we need to flood-fill the lowest number in each component. We do this with repeated application until the fix-point `⍣≡` of processing Moore neighbourhoods `⌺3 3`. To get the von Neumann neighbours, we reshape the 9 elements in the Moore neighbourhood into a 4-row 2-column matrix with `4 2⍴` and use `⊢/` to select the right column. We remove any 0s with `0~⍨` them prepend `,` the original value `⍵[2;2]` (even if 0) and have `⌊/` select the smallest value:

```
        {⌊/⍵[2;2],0~⍨⊢/4 2⍴⍵}⌺3 3⍣≡⍸@⊢m
0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 2 2 0 4
0 2 0 0 4
0 2 0 0 4
```

We map the values to indices by finding their `⊢` indices `⍳⍨` in the unique elements of `∘∪` 0 followed by `,` the ravelled matrix `,`:

```
        (⊢⍳⍨∘∪0,,){⌊/⍵[2;2],0~⍨⊢/4 2⍴⍵}⌺3 3⍣≡⍸@⊢m
1 1 2 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
1 3 3 1 4
1 3 1 1 4
1 3 1 1 4
```

And decrement which adjusts back to begin with zero:

```
        ¯1+(⊢⍳⍨∘∪0,,){⌊/⍵[2;2],0~⍨⊢/4 2⍴⍵}⌺3 3⍣≡⍸@⊢m
0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 2 2 0 3
0 2 0 0 3
0 2 0 0 3
```

Comment: Nice. I've not seen `(⍳+/)@⊢m` before. It would be nice if you could briefly annotate also, what does `4 2⍴` do here, it looks like a clever trick, but it's not clear what

Comment: @AdamNathan I've inserted some explanations, although `(⍳+/)` was very silly of me on an all-one vector, so I've simplified that.

Comment: Thanks. Wouldn't it be simpler to use the max instead of filtering 0?

Comment: @AdamNathan You could use max instead of min, but you still have to prevent 0s from getting non-0 neighbours' values, so you'd have to multiply by the sign of the current value or something like that: `¯1+(∪⍤,⍳⊢){⍵[2;2](×⍤⊣×⌈/⍤,)⊢/4 2⍴⍵}⌺3 3⍣≡⍸@⊢m`

Comment: Reviewing this again, I noticed that it's a problem when the top left corner is *not* the background. How would you resolve this? Sorting `(∪⍤,⍳⊢)` seems a bit ugly.

Comment: Nicely spotted. Fixed.